# Many BETWEEN and AND wrong answer mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I use a query A bit complex. There is BETWEEN and and. What I optain is the query with all the value of the database. the field classe = 'Vehicule' is no more reconized and the hole table elements are selected
Here the simple code

```
$query = "SELECT
publier.classe AS 'classe',
publier.sclasse AS 'sclasse',
publier.region AS 'region',
publier.sujet AS 'sujet',
publier.prix AS 'prix',
publier.details AS 'details',
publier.pdate AS 'pdate',
publier.ptime AS 'ptime',
publier.photo1 AS 'photo1',
publier.photo2 AS 'photo2',
publier.photo3 AS 'photo3',
publier.photo3 AS 'photo4',
publier.courriel AS 'courriel',
info.Ville AS 'Ville' ,
info.Nom AS 'Nom',
info.Prenom AS 'Prenom',
info.Telephone AS 'Telephone',
info.Courriel AS 'Courriel'
FROM 
publier LEFT JOIN info 
ON
publier.courriel = info.Courriel 
        WHERE classe = 'Vehicule' AND  
        (details LIKE \"%$trimmed%\") OR 
        (sujet  LIKE \"%$trimmed%\") AND 
        (pdate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY) AND NOW()) AND 
        (prix BETWEEN '".$pmin."' AND '".$pmax."') 
ORDER BY prix ASC";
```

Comment: 1. SQL injection, 2. SQL Injection and 3. Did I mention SQL Injection?

Answer (score 2):

Be careful of how the conditions in WHERE are grouped:

```
WHERE classe = 'Vehicule' AND  (details like \"%$trimmed%\")OR(sujet  like \"%$trimmed%\")  AND (pdate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY) AND NOW()) AND (prix BETWEEN '".$pmin."' AND '".$pmax."')
```

This sentence

```
WHERE A AND B OR C
```

is not the same as

```
WHERE A AND (B OR C)
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

change

```
 (details like \"%$trimmed%\")OR(sujet  like \"%$trimmed%\")
```

to

```
 (details like \"%$trimmed%\" OR sujet like \"%$trimmed%\")
```

**OR** is a culprit here, when outside parenthesis all preceding conditions may be false and results will still be returned.